# Get Millisecond from January 1st 00:00:00:000 with Javascript

Tags: javascript

How would I get the millisecond from January 1st 00:00:00:000 (of **this** year) with Javascript? For example, January 1st 00:00:00:000 would give me 0 and December 31st 23:59:59:999 would give me 31536000000.

Comment: make a [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for that time and call `.getMilliseconds()` ?

Comment: "December 31st 23:59:59:999 would give me 31,536,000,000". Or 31,622,400,000 if it was a leap year, presumably?

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: wait, do you want from Jan 1st of THIS year? or from Jan 1 1970?

Comment: Sorry with the lack of details with my question. I wanted from Jan 1st of THIS YEAR. I tried working out some math (24*60*60*1000 and stuff) but it gave me wrong numbers.

Comment: As noted by @Tetsudou and Boann this is not a duplicate. The OP wants the time diff in milliseconds from the beginning of "this" year - not Epoch Time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get you a new date (now) as ms from Jan 1st 1970. ([Epoch Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time))

```
var ms = new Date().getTime();
```

If you want it from Jan 1st of *this* year you can use.

```
var janFirstThisYear = new Date('1/1/2014').getTime();
var now = new Date().getTime();

var ms = now - janFirstThisYear;
```

*Note*: this is hard coded to the year 2014.  Depending on your needs this could be re-worked to automatically extract 'this' year.

e.g.

```
var now = new Date();
var thisYear = now.getFullYear();
var janFirstThisYear = new Date(thisYear, 0, 1);
var ms = now.getTime() - janFirstThisYear.getTime();
```

Comment: -1 for your quick response without specifying 1970 - I evened it out after your edits :P

Comment: thanks @Shaded (yeah I didn't know if the OP wanted this year only, or from "all time" ;-)

Answer (score -3):

For example:

x = new Date;
x.getMilliseconds();

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with the question. This gets the milliseconds of the *current time* (i.e. Nov 13 4:26:___), not the time in milliseconds since a certain date. (Therefore, it always returns a number from 0 to 1000.)